# Why Maven build removed my folders and files on Desktop

Tags: macos, maven, properties

I had a Maven project with a pom.xml in which I declared the properties-section in a similar
fashion:

```
<properties>
    <buildDirectory>/Users/myname/Desktop</buildDirectory>
</properties>
```

The reason I did this was because I wanted to override the default location of the output folder (which is target by default), just to see that it actually puts the build on that location (Desktop). When I later ran the **mvn** command with *clean install* goals I suddenly saw that some of my folders was disappearing one by one. So I just canceled the process during the build because I was almost about to lose everything on my Desktop.

No I have lost almost all of my folders which I had on my Desktop. :(

Is there a way for me to be able to get those files and folders in which I had before I ran the command, back on place?

Im using Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)

(Unfortunately I had no backup or anything ...so Im lost here)

Any kind of advice to check would be extremely thankful..

Comment: The buildDirectory is by default the `target` directory within your project and is removed by using `mvn clean` which is intended to remove all the build results to begin from scratch if you like...first strong recommendation is to keep the defaults in Maven cause they have a reason. This is called Convention Over configuration. So just don't change things if you don't understand how they work. So if you don't make backups of your machine then you really lost (cause one rule in IT is to make backup's). You might check the trash on MacOS if they might have been put there but I have my doubts...

Comment: I just realized this was such a stupid thing to do. I guess I was too tired since I was working very late on this thing and just too tired to realize what I was doing and the consequences. 

Now....is there any special directories where removed files and folders (through mvc clean) might be placed ?   Or is this the end game?

Comment: As I mentioned "Trash"...otherwise you are lost ....